# Master and slave threads should shutdown using ctrl+c

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where the Main class initializes and starts a master thread. This master thread starts `n` slave threads. The program should terminate using `Ctrl+C`. Master thread must stop slave threads and finally stop itself.
I've read a lot about `addShutdownHook` and here is my simplified implementation:

```
package dictator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Master m = new Master();
        m.start();
    }
}

class Master extends Thread {

    List<Slave> slaveMonitor = new ArrayList<Slave>();

    public Master() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Slave slaveThread = new Slave();
            slaveMonitor.add(slaveThread);
        }

        Thread shutDown = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.format("%nShutting down threads...%n");
                    for (Slave s : slaveMonitor) {
                        s.interrupt();
                        s.join();
                    }
                    interrupt()
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutDown);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Slave s : slaveMonitor) {
            s.start();
        }

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " - Master");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(getName() + " interrupted.");
               break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getName() + " exiting.");
    }
}

class Slave extends Thread {

    public Slave() {}

    @Override 
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(getName() + " - Slave");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(getName() + " interrupted.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `addShutdownHook` catches the signal and terminates all slaves threads, but I'm not seen the master thread exiting (lines `System.out.println(getName() + " interrupted.");` and `System.out.println(getName() + " exiting.");` in master's run body.

Here is my terminal's output:

```
Thread-1 - Slave
Thread-2 - Slave
Thread-3 - Slave
Thread-0 - Master
Thread-4 - Slave
Thread-0 - Master
^C
Shutting down threads...
Thread-1 interrupted.
Thread-2 interrupted.
Thread-3 interrupted.
Thread-4 interrupted.
```

Shouldn’t I see the line following lines? *What I'm I doing wrong?*

```
Thread-0 interrupted.
Thread-0 exiting.
```

### Changed Master Thread

```
class Master extends Thread {

    List<Slave> slaveMonitor = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Thread> killList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Master() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Slave slaveThread = new Slave();
            slaveMonitor.add(slaveThread);
        }
        killList.add(this);

        Thread shutDown = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    killList.addAll(slaveMonitor);
                    Collections.reverse(killList);
                    System.out.format("%nShutting down threads...%n");
                    for (Thread t : killList) {
                        t.interrupt();
                        t.join();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Interrupted shutdown process");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        };
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutDown);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shutdown thread never interrupt the master thread. It is a separate thread from the Master thread so when you call

```
   interrupt()
```

in its body you are asking this thread to interrupt itself. You need to add the master thread to the list of thread to terminate.

Change your code to :

```
  List<Thread> killList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
   ....
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Slave slaveThread = new Slave();
        slaveMonitor.add(slaveThread);
    }
    killList.addAll(slaveMonitor);
    killList.add(this);
```

and use the `killList` to terminate threads.

Comment: This works! But, my `killList` should be filled last moment because I don't know how many slaves are running (slaveMonitor adds and removes threads). If I place the last two lines in `shutDown` thread run() body, to construct `killList`, the master thread doesn't stop. Any Ideas?

Comment: Simple: create methods addSlave, removeSlave which operates on both lists. I didnt want to directly use slaveMonitor because it strip down the meaning and will requires test like `if( slaveMonitor.get(i) != this ) do something normal`. Also check if the thread is running before interrupting it.

Comment: Thank you. I took the approach to fill `killList` with `this` in Master's constructor and add all slave threads in `shutDown` thread, just before send interrupt signals. If I come into troubles, I will switch to your suggestion. You may see my answer for my approach.

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a program which makes use of two types of threads: slaves (sensors) and master.

The slave threads collect measurements and forward them to the master thread

For sake of simplicity the slaves measure the current time (System.currentTimeMillis()). Only the master thread outputs the values to the console. The measures are stored in a shared variable. The number of slaves shall be read from the console.